# find sum of time from two dimensional array

Tags: php

Hello i'm going to find the sum but there shows error like `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` how to ckeck error

My code is

i get time like this

```
$SQL = "SELECT o_duration FROM total WHERE location=('".$location_c[$k]."') AND sub_cat=('".$id."') AND dateid BETWEEN '".$trgD."' AND '".$date2."'";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

$s="0";
$duration_c[$k]=array();
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$duration_c[$k][$s]= $db_field['o_duration'];

$s++;
}
```

Than i print it in the table with a for loop

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++)
{ 

?>
<td width="154" class="alt" align="center"><?php  echo sum_the_time($duration_c[$i])
?></td> <?php } ?>



function sum_the_time($times) {

  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time1)
  { 
list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
$seconds += $hour*3600;
$seconds += $minute*60;
$seconds += $second;
 }
 $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
 $seconds -= $hours*3600;
 $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
 $seconds -= $minutes*60;
 // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
 return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
 }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: there shows error  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @ganna this is due to because of the value at the `$duration_c[$i]` is not set. check by echoing it that is there any value or not.

Comment: you can use `sum(o_duration)` in sql query itself to get sum of time.

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means the array you're passing to the function is empty (or not an array)

Add a condition to check if it's valid

```
if(is_array($times) and count($times)>0){
  foreach ($times as $time1){
    (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: `lenght` is not a function in PHP, use `count($times)`